# For what $x>0$ series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

For what $x>0$ series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$ is convergent?

By logarithmic test, 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(n \log\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}\right)$$ is infinite for $0<x<1$. So for $x\in (0,1)$, series is convergent. Am I correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ is well approximated by $2\sqrt{n}$, the required series is convergent iff the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,x^{2\sqrt{n}}$$ is convergent.  Since $$\int_0^\infty\,\exp\big(-\alpha\sqrt{t})\,\text{d}t=\frac{2}{\alpha^2}<\infty$$ for all $\alpha>0$, the required series is convergent for all $x\in(0,1)$ by the Integral Test.  Surely, if $x\geq 1$, the required series is divergent.  Ergo, you are correct.

Comment: Why do you compute $\int_0^\infty\, e^{\big(-\alpha\sqrt{t})}\,\text{d}t$ ?

Comment: Let $\alpha:=-2\,\ln(x)>0$ if $0<x<1$, so that $x=\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$.  Then, the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\,x^{2\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent if and only if the said intgral is convergent.

Comment: oh i got it. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

By comparing with an integral, you can see that the exponent
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {\sqrt k} \approx 2\sqrt{n}$$
so the series converges iff $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are true.$$$$
First if $x\ge1$ then $x^{1+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\ge x\ge1=>$ sum divergent.$$$$
Second if $0<x<1$. 
$$
\\1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt n=>
\\x^{1+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\le x^{\sqrt{n}}
\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\frac{1}{x^\sqrt n}}{\ln n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}\cdot \ln (\frac{1}{x})>1=>
$$
sum convergent.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Логарифмический_признак_сходимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)